# Change label/button text depending of the bool status

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and i'm trying to change a label/button text depending of the bool status . Can you help me ? THANK YOU ( im using visual studio with their default buttons)

Comment: C++ doesn't even have standard buttons or labels. Apart from the endless possibilities of what problem you're having, no one can know which buttons and labels you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your form elements by their Name property.
For example if you have a button named `button1`, you can edit its Text property like this:

```
button1->Text = "new name";
```

It's the same for labels, text boxes and many other elements.
About the bool status you say, I don't know what are you trying to do.

Comment: hei . thanks for answer . i know how i can change a button text but i need to change it when the bool status changes from true to false or viceversa

Comment: But which bool status? I don't know what you mean, maybe the _Enabled_ property of the element?  
So you can code `if(button1->Enabled)`

Comment: i have a bool from another class . it changes sometimes    if (isbool == true) this->button1->text = L"something" else this->button1->text = L"otherthing" thats what im trying to do

Comment: You don´t need to compare that ´isbool == true´ because if  isbool is true, it will enter if statement.   
What is L?